# I want to make a button with icon on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, dart

I have a question. I want to make a button that has an icon on it. How should I do it?

I have tried using an `ElevatedButton`. It does not seem to be really close to the button that I wanted.

Here's the code that I have written:

```
child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Masuk",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  10,
                  0,
                  0,
                  0,
                ),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Here's the sample that I wanted to make:
[image: heres the samo]

Comment: you can check here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SizedBox(
      height: 60,
      child: MaterialButton(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Opacity(
              opacity: 0.0,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "MASUK",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            CircleAvatar(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_forward,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        color: Colors.indigo[400],
        disabledColor: Colors.indigo[400],
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
```

Comment: sorry can i ask you something? how do i make it smaller? do i need to use padding right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: You also need to change the SizedBox's height and fontSize.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ElevatedButton to Container and put IconButton instead of Icon

Comment: is it will affecting text? when i want to move the icon to right the text moving to the left

Comment: Oh... i got your point, you wondered about layout of your button. Then replace Row to Stack, and set the text location with Center and set the icon location with Positioned

Answer (score 0):

You can have a button with an icon using the following code.
(Icon will appear on left side)

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
    label: const Text("Test"),
    onPressed: (){
        //Function
    },
);
```

You can also create a custom widget and wrap it with `InkWell` and use the `onTap` function.

Example:

```
InkWell(
      onTap: (){
        // function
      },
      child: myWidget())
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this also: Above answer is also correct.

```
Container(
          width: 250,
          height: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.indigo[400],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),             
          ),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              // function
            },
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 15,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_forward,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 15.0,
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'MASUK',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 15,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 15.0,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A very simple code to make a button like yours is,

```
            RaisedButton.icon(
                  icon: const Text('UPADATE'),
                  label: Icon(Icons.next_plan),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/simple_animations

```
 ////i used this package to show animation button like this   
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:simple_animations/simple_animations.dart';
        
        enum AnimationType { opacity, translateX }
        
        class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
          final double delay;
          final Widget child;
        
          const FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child);
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            final tween = MultiTween<AnimationType>()
              ..add(AnimationType.opacity, Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
                Duration(milliseconds: 500),)
              ..add(
                AnimationType.translateX,
                Tween(begin: 30.0, end: 1.0),
                Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              );
        
            return PlayAnimation<MultiTweenValues<AnimationType>>(
              delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
              duration: tween.duration,
              tween: tween,
              child: child,
              builder: (context, child, value) => Opacity(
                opacity: value.get(AnimationType.opacity),
                child: Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(value.get(AnimationType.translateX), 0), child: child),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
/////how i used this code 
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bookshelf_app/resource/colors.dart';
import 'package:bookshelf_app/views/Login/LogInPage.dart';
import 'package:bookshelf_app/views/SplashScreen/FadeAnimation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashPageState createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _scaleController;
  AnimationController _scale2Controller;
  AnimationController _widthController;
  AnimationController _positionController;

  Animation<double> _scaleAnimation;
  Animation<double> _scale2Animation;
  Animation<double> _widthAnimation;
  Animation<double> _positionAnimation;

  bool hideIcon = false;

  startTime() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 5);
    return new Timer(_duration, myPage);
  }

  void myPage() {
    _scaleController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    startTime();
    _scaleController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));

    _scaleAnimation =
    Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.8).animate(_scaleController)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          _widthController.forward();
        }
      });

    _widthController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600));

    _widthAnimation =
    Tween<double>(begin: 80.0, end: 300.0).animate(_widthController)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          _positionController.forward();
        }
      });

    _positionController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000));

    _positionAnimation =
    Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 215.0).animate(_positionController)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          setState(() {
            hideIcon = true;
          });
          _scale2Controller.forward();
        }
      });

    _scale2Controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));

    _scale2Animation =
    Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 32.0).animate(_scale2Controller)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
//        Navigator.pushReplacement(
//            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SplashScreen(sec: 1)));
          getSessionValues();
//        Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.fade, child: LoginPage()));
        }
      });
  }

  getSessionValues() async {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
               LogInMain()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .width;
    final double height = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .height;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                  child: FadeAnimation(
                      1.6,
                      Container(
                        width: width / 1.3,
                        height: height / 2.8,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage('assets/BOOKHUB.png'),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      )),
                )),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:20.0,left:20,right:20),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
//                  SizedBox(height: height / 30,),
                  FadeAnimation(
                      1.0,
                      Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "BookShops and libraries are a backstage of success!!",
                          style: GoogleFonts.vollkorn(
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.7),
                              height: 1.4,
                              fontSize: 24),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height / 20,
                  ),
                  FadeAnimation(
                      1.3,
                      AnimatedBuilder(
                        animation: _scaleController,
                        builder: (context, child) =>
                            Transform.scale(
                                scale: _scaleAnimation.value,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: AnimatedBuilder(
                                    animation: _widthController,
                                    builder: (context, child) =>
                                        Container(
                                          width: _widthAnimation.value,
                                          height: 80,
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                  .circular(50),
                                              color:  MyColorTheme.darkGreen.withOpacity(
                                                  .4)),
                                          child: InkWell(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              _scaleController.forward();
                                            },
                                            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                                              AnimatedBuilder(
                                                animation: _positionController,
                                                builder: (context, child) =>
                                                    Positioned(
                                                      left: _positionAnimation
                                                          .value,
                                                      child: AnimatedBuilder(
                                                        animation: _scale2Controller,
                                                        builder: (context,
                                                            child) =>
                                                            Transform.scale(
                                                                scale:
                                                                _scale2Animation
                                                                    .value,
                                                                child: Container(
                                                                  width: 60,
                                                                  height: 60,
                                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                      shape:
                                                                      BoxShape
                                                                          .circle,
                                                                      color: MyColorTheme.darkGreen),
                                                                  child: hideIcon ==
                                                                      false
                                                                      ? Icon(
                                                                    Icons
                                                                        .arrow_forward,
                                                                    color:
                                                                    Colors
                                                                        .white,
                                                                  )
                                                                      : Container(),
                                                                )),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                              ),
                                            ]),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                  ),
                                )),
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: height / 20,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```